# Javascript - Unable to import module from node package

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ecmascript-6

I am developing a WordPress plugin for which I'm using `@wordpress/data` package which I defined as dependency in my `package.json` file.

I checked `node_modules` directory and that package is present there.

When I try to import like

```js
import { registerStore } from '@wordpress/data';
```

There is no warning/error in the build process, but in browser I am getting the error

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerStore' of undefined.
```

Comment: did you install npm install @wordpress/data --save ??

Comment: @sonEtLumiere Yes, I did. Everything is at place inside `node_modules` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for @wordpress/data possible registerStore is an old function. Check if register is exported etc instead. If using vscode try control+space keys in between the brackets to see what you can import from that package.

Comment: import { createReduxStore, register } from '@wordpress/data'; is the example provided in the docs

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is also not working and throwing same error.